# how to call oracle web service using asp.net web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, oracle

How to call Oracle web service using asp.net web service?  Is there a difference between calling asp.net web service and calling Oracle web service from asp.net web service?

I found how to call asp.net web service from another one but not Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the web service (any web service) has a [WSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx), then you can call it from .Net code. Just point the [WCF Configuration utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) at the URL, or import the WSDL and it will generate the proxy for you.

Comment: Woops! Wrong link for the second WCF utility. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Is there a difference between calling oracle web service and calling asp.net web service ?

Comment: No. If they are using SOAP as the protocol then they will be identical.